# Light message not working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i am trying to load a light using light message but it is not working. Here is the code

namespace gazebo
{
class WorldPluginTutorial : public WorldPlugin
{
public: WorldPluginTutorial() : WorldPlugin()
{
printf("Hello World!\n");
}

```
public: void Load(physics::WorldPtr _world, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
        {
          printf("Hello World Load!\n");
      this->model = _world;
          printf("%s\n", (this->model->GetName()).c_str());
      
          // Initialize ros, if it has not already bee initialized.
        if (!ros::isInitialized())
        {
            int argc = 0;
            char **argv = NULL;
            ros::init(argc, argv, "gazebo_client",
            ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
        }

            // Create our ROS node. This acts in a similar manner to
        // the Gazebo node
        this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle("gazebo_client"));

        // Create a named topic, and subscribe to it.
        ros::SubscribeOptions so =
        ros::SubscribeOptions::create<std_msgs::Float32>(
            "/" + this->model->GetName() + "/vel_cmd",
            1,
            boost::bind(&WorldPluginTutorial::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
            ros::VoidPtr(), &this->rosQueue);
        this->rosSub = this->rosNode->subscribe(so);

            // Spin up the queue helper thread.
        this->rosQueueThread =
            std::thread(std::bind(&WorldPluginTutorial::QueueThread, this));

        }
    public: void OnRosMsg(const std_msgs::Float32ConstPtr &_msg)
    {
        //this->SetVelocity(_msg->data);
    printf("Entered WorldPluginTutorial::OnRosMsg\n");
        //w->InsertModelFile("model://sun");
    //physics::WorldPtr w = this->model->GetWorld();
    //unsigned int i = this->model->LightCount();
    sdf::SDF point;
    point.SetFromString("<?xml version='1.0' ?>\
        <sdf version='1.5'>\
        <!-- Light Source -->\
        <light name='point_light' type='point'>\
                <pose frame=''>2 -2 1 0 -0 0</pose>\
                <diffuse>0.5 0.5 0.5 1</diffuse>\
                <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>\
                <attenuation>\
                    <range>20</range>\
                    <constant>0.5</constant>\
                    <linear>0.01</linear>\
                    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>\
                </attenuation>\
                <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>\
                <direction>0 0 -1</direction>\
        </light>\
        </sdf>");
    sdf::ElementPtr light = point.Root()->GetElement("light");
    msgs::Light msg = gazebo::msgs::LightFromSDF(light);
    //this->model->LoadLigt(light);
    transport::NodePtr node(new transport::Node());

    node->Init(this->model->GetName());

    transport::PublisherPtr lightPub 
        = node->Advertise<msgs::Light>("~/light");

    lightPub->Publish(msg);

    unsigned int i = this->model->Lights().size();
        printf("Light count = %d\n", i);    
        //w->InsertModelFile("model://sun");
        //w->InsertModelFile("model://sun");
    }

/// \brief ROS helper function that processes messages
    private: void QueueThread()
    {
        static const double timeout = 0.01;
        while (this->rosNode->ok())
        {
                this->rosQueue.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
        }
    }
    private: physics::WorldPtr model;
private: std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;
    /// \brief A ROS subscriber
    private: ros::Subscriber rosSub;

    /// \brief A ROS callbackqueue that helps process messages
    private: ros::CallbackQueue rosQueue;

    /// \brief A thread the keeps running the rosQueue
    private: std::thread rosQueueThread;
```

};
GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(WorldPluginTutorial)
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17431/light-message-not-working/) by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Could you try advertising to `~/factory/light` instead? Also, when you run Gazebo in verbose mode `gazebo --verbose`, do you see any errors?

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on 2017-10-06**:
Thanks ~/factory/light works, but still there is an issue. Light is added but not visible. When I send the same message next time I get an error the "Light [point_light] already exists.", however, the first light gets visible in Gazebo then. How can refresh the world instantaneously to view the light?